# Open URL Containing Emoji Using AppleScript

Tags: applescript, url, emoji

This AppleScript creates a new email in my default mailer, but the balloon emoji (“”) in the subject is converted to the question mark character (“?”).

```
set theURL to "mailto:<Wile.E.Coyote@acme.com>?&subject=Happy Birthday &body=Wile:

beep beep.

- Road Runner"
open location theURL
```

How do I open a URL that contains an emoji using AppleScript?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is no simple way to encode Emoji in AppleScript itself; alternatives include using:

- ASObjC
- Shell command to Perl, Python (somewhat more involved since
  Apple no longer installs Python with macOS), etc.
- JXA

I settled on the `percent encode` handler within Shane Stanley’s [RegexAndStuffLib v1.0.7](https://s3.amazonaws.com/latenightsw.com/ShaneLibs/RegexAndStuffLib_stuff.zip)

```
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later
use scripting additions
use script "RegexAndStuffLib" version "1.0.7"
set newline to (ASCII character 13) & (ASCII character 10)
set blankline to newline & newline
set theRecipient to percent encode "Wile.E.Coyote<wec@acme.com>"
set theSubject to percent encode "Happy Birthday "
set theBody to percent encode "Wile:" & blankline & "beep beep." & blankline & "- Road Runner"
set theURL to "mailto:" & theRecipient & "?subject=" & theSubject & "&body=" & theBody
open location theURL
```

Comment: `mailto:` is defined by [RFC 6068](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6068), which [specifies](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6068#page-8) `%0D%0A` as the newline character.